# How to pass Redux store to components imported from packages?

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

Say you have a project split up over two repo's: main and account.
From the main repo I install the account repo as a dependency and import the account components.
When I create a Redux store in the main part of the app, how does one go about passing that store to the account components? My idea is to connect a container component in the main part and pass all state/actions needed in a single object. Then in the account part I'll create a Redux context feeding this object to all components that need it.
This will work, but it feels like I'm reproducing the Provider/connect functionality from the 'react-redux' package. However, I can't connect in the account part directly since the Provider is located in the main part. Can anyone think of a more elegant solution?

Comment: You need to provide code snippet of what you are doing or trying to achieve

Comment: Please check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No I don't, this is architecture talk not code talk. Thanks!

Comment: You really do: without a concrete example of anything specific it's difficult to understand the precise problem you're solving. You can connect any component to Redux regardless of where it's initially defined.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article: https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps/ . Basically you can create multiple providers and separate your application so that each part has its own redux tree.

If you need to nest them then in v6 you could do something like this: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#multiple-stores , don't know if that is the case with redux v7 since it doesn't use context anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but this pattern is not recommended if components/sub apps share state with the parent component/app